# javascript when select first dropdown list the second dropdown list will populate base on the first dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Please help.

I have 3 tables

1. `PublicationType` table has columns publicationTypeID, description
2. `Quantities` table has columns quantityId, description
3. `Agent Publicationquantities` table has columns publicationTypeID, quantityId

How to write jQuery or Json in MVC3 when user select `Publication` dropdown list  then the second dropdown list is the quantity

Dropdown list will populate based on the Publication dropdown list selected (check with the third table AgentPublicationQuantity)

Example if the user select publication id=9 Test Publication 3  then the Quantity should populate half,full, half&full for the user to select.)

From code below so far on the view page, I have two dropdown lists:

1. `PublicationType` populate Publications
2. `Quantity`  populate quantities list

I wanted the Quantity to populate base on the PublicationType dropdown list value, because different publication has different available quantity.

Here is my code

```
    public ActionResult Create(int agentID)
    {
        // Get data to display create page.
        AgentPublicationOrder publication = new AgentPublicationOrder(); // Declare new instance of Agent Adjustment object.
        AgentViewModel viewModel = new AgentViewModel(agentID, this.User.Identity.Name);    // Create lightweight agent view model.          
        AgentPublicationOrderViewModel publicationviewmodel = new AgentPublicationOrderViewModel(agentID);

        ViewBag.loggedInUserName = viewModel.loggedInUserName;
        ViewBag.fullContactName = viewModel.fullContactName;
        ViewBag.agentID = viewModel.agentID;

           // get data to populate dropdowlist
        using (var db1 = new AgentPublicationTypesDBContext())
        { 

            var agentquantityFromDB = db1.AgentPublicationTypePublicationQuantities.Select(x => x.publicationQuantityId).ToList();

            // dropdownlist pulicationType
            ViewBag.AgentPublicationTypes = db1.AgentPublicationTypes.Where(x => agentquantityFromDB.Contains(x.id) && x.inactiveDate > DateTime.Today || !x.inactiveDate.HasValue).OrderBy(a => a.description).ToList();

              //dropdownlist Quantity
           ViewBag.Quantities = db1.PublicationQuantities.Where(x => agentquantityFromDB.Contains(x.id) || x.inactiveDate == null && x.inactiveDate > DateTime.Today).OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();
        }
        return View(publication);
    }
```

Here is my view page

```
<div class="three_column_row">
            <div class="three_column_col">
                <div class="labelCell2">

                    Publication:
                </div>
                <div class="editorCell">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.agentPublicationTypeid, new SelectList(@ViewBag.AgentPublicationTypes, "id", "description", (Model.agentPublicationTypeid != 0 ? Model.agentPublicationTypeid : -1)), "--Select One--")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="three_column_col">
                <div class="labelCell2">
                   Qty:
                </div>
                <div class="editorCell">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.quantityId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Quantities, "id", "description"), "--Select One--")


                </div>
            </div>


        </div>`
```

Comment: Billy I have not start javascript or json code yet. i am doing some research how to to used javascript or jason to do this. ( i am very new with javascript /jason)

Comment: it's json...not jason